# How to retain the dropdown and their selection after pressing back in browser

Tags: java, jsp

Having 2 dropdowns based on one drop down other will populate and open webpage. But when i press back in the webpage the 2nd dropdown is not seen.

The source below is the java code which i used. Please tell me how to use the location.hash property in this code to retain the dropdown.

I tried using the location.hash and location.href but it's not working. Please help me  resolve my problem.

```
<script language="javascript">
    var selectmenu=document.getElementById("mymenu")
    selectmenu.onchange=function()
    {
       var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex]
       if (chosenoption.value!="nothing")
       {
          window.open(chosenoption.value,"_parent")
       }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say, the design not very good.

1. When the dropdown value is changed (say on Page A), call a server side action listener (or a simple servlet, may be by simply submitting the form).
2. Then let the server redirect (or forward) to next page (say Page B). In this process you will get a chance to save the submitted value. You can save the submitted value in the session.
3. While rendering Page A, check if any value is present in the session.